# Stastic NAT with multiple WANs - internet connectivity issue

Tags: nat, cisco-asa, wide-area-network

I am having an issue with my ASA. I have set multiple WAN and static NAT in ASA. I can get via specific ports from those WAN addresses to my server, but I am having issue with internet connectivity. I cannot browse from that server to outside. What am I missing?

```
   : Saved

: 
: Serial Number: XXXXXXXXX
: Hardware:   ASA5508, 8192 MB RAM, CPU Atom C2000 series 2000 MHz, 1 CPU (8 cores)
: Written by enable_15 at 22:59:07.919 GMT Wed Nov 30 2016
!
ASA Version 9.6(1) 
!
hostname HC-ClientASA
enable password xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx encrypted
names
ip local pool Test_DHCP_VPN 10.20.30.0-10.20.30.100 mask 255.255.255.0

!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address xxx.xxx.xxx.74 255.255.255.248 
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/2
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/3
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/4
 description WAN for ServerTV
 nameif ServerTV
 security-level 80
 ip address 192.168.96.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/5
 description GuestWiFi interface for Access poitns
 nameif GuestWiFi
 security-level 100
 ip address 172.16.64.1 255.255.248.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/6
 description Parking interface To Server
 nameif ParkingInterface
 security-level 100
 ip address 172.16.17.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/7
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/8
 description Old WAN Interface
 nameif WAN_OLD
 security-level 0
 ip address xxx.xxx.xxx.137 255.255.255.252 
!
interface Management1/1
 management-only
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
ftp mode passive
clock timezone GMT 0
object network obj_any
 subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
object network OLD_GW
 host xxx.xxx.xxx.138
 description Old GW Interface
object network GuestWiFi_NAT_OLD
 subnet 172.16.64.0 255.255.248.0
 description GuestWiFi OLD WAN
object network NEW_GW
 host xxx.xxx.xxx.73
 description Telia New Gateway
object network TestGw
 subnet 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
 description Test NAT
object network VPN_POOL_10.20.30.0
 subnet 10.20.30.0 255.255.255.128
 description VPN Pool
object network GuestWiFiNAT
 subnet 172.16.64.0 255.255.248.0
 description NAT for guestWiFi
object network inside_NAT_OLD
 subnet 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
 description Inside OLD WAN
object network ParkingSystem
 subnet 172.16.17.0 255.255.255.0
 description Parking system NAT
object network ParkingSystem_NAT_OLD
 subnet 172.16.17.0 255.255.255.0
 description Parking S OLD WAN
object network ParkingSystemServers
 subnet xxx.xxx.xxx.0 255.255.255.0
 description Public WAN from Parking System
object network ParkingSystemSubnet
 subnet 172.16.17.0 255.255.255.0
 description Parking System Subnet
object network GuestWiFi
 subnet 172.16.64.0 255.255.248.0
 description GuestWiFi object
object network ParkingServer1
 host 172.16.17.3
 description ParkingServer1
object network ParkingServer2
 host 172.16.17.4
 description Parking server 2
object service TCP_Parking_771
 service tcp source eq 771 
 description Port for Parking server1
object service TCP_Parking_771_U
 service udp source eq 771 
 description Port for parking server UDP
object service TCP_Parking2_9100
 service tcp source eq 9100 
 description Parking for server 2 TCP
object service TCP_Parking2_9100_U
 service udp source eq 9100 
 description TCP_Parking2_9100_UDP
object network TestLabNAT
 subnet 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
 description TestLab NAT
object network GuestWiFiLAB
 subnet 172.16.64.0 255.255.248.0
object network ParkingInterfaceLAB
 subnet 172.16.17.0 255.255.255.0
 description Test Lab interface
object network ServerInternet
 subnet 192.168.96.0 255.255.255.0
 description Server Internet In
object network ServerTVLab
 subnet 192.168.96.0 255.255.255.0
 description Test Lab
object network ServerTV_OLD
 subnet 192.168.96.0 255.255.255.0
object network ServerServer
 host 192.168.96.2
 description ConnectionToServer
object network NETWORK_OBJ_10.20.30.0_25
 subnet 10.20.30.0 255.255.255.128
object network Parking
 subnet 172.16.17.0 255.255.255.0
object network ParkingNAT
 subnet 172.16.17.0 255.255.255.0
object network ParkingSystems
 host xxx.xxx.xxx.120
object network ParkingInterfaceOLD_WAN
 subnet 172.16.17.0 255.255.255.0
object network Server1
 subnet 192.168.96.0 255.255.255.0
object network Server2
 host 192.168.96.2
object service iPerfServer
 service tcp source eq 5001 
object network ServerNet
 subnet 192.168.96.0 255.255.255.0
object network WAN2
 host xxx.xxx.xxx.75
object network ServerTV2
 host 192.168.96.2
object network HostNatToOutside
 subnet 192.168.96.0 255.255.255.0
object-group icmp-type DM_INLINE_ICMP_1
 icmp-object echo
 icmp-object echo-reply
 icmp-object time-exceeded
 icmp-object traceroute
 icmp-object unreachable
object-group icmp-type DM_INLINE_ICMP_2
 icmp-object echo
 icmp-object echo-reply
 icmp-object time-exceeded
 icmp-object traceroute
 icmp-object unreachable
object-group service ParkingObj tcp-udp
 port-object eq 771
 port-object eq 9100
object-group service ParkingPortsNAT tcp-udp
 description OpenPortsForParking
 port-object eq 771
 port-object eq 9100
object-group protocol TCPUDP
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group icmp-type DM_INLINE_ICMP_4
 icmp-object echo
 icmp-object echo-reply
 icmp-object time-exceeded
 icmp-object traceroute
 icmp-object unreachable
object-group service DM_INLINE_SERVICE_1
 service-object tcp-udp destination eq 4500 
 service-object tcp-udp destination eq 500 
 service-object tcp-udp destination eq 5001 
 service-object tcp-udp destination eq 8090 
 service-object tcp destination eq https 
 service-object tcp destination eq ssh 
 service-object udp destination eq snmp 
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_6
 network-object object ParkingServer1
 network-object object ParkingServer2
object-group service NOC_Auth tcp-udp
 port-object eq 8090
object-group service VPN_IPSec tcp-udp
 port-object eq 4500
 port-object eq 500
object-group service iPerf tcp-udp
 port-object eq 5001
access-list inside_access_in extended permit icmp any any object-group DM_INLINE_ICMP_1 
access-list inside_access_in extended permit object-group TCPUDP any any eq domain 
access-list inside_access_in extended permit ip any any 
access-list Test_Guest remark GuestWiFi network
access-list Test_Guest standard permit 172.16.64.0 255.255.248.0 
access-list Test_Guest remark ParkingNetwork
access-list Test_Guest standard permit 172.16.17.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list Test_Guest standard permit 192.168.96.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list Test_Guest standard permit 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list GuestWiFi_access_in extended permit icmp any any object-group DM_INLINE_ICMP_2 
access-list GuestWiFi_access_in extended permit object-group TCPUDP any any eq domain 
access-list GuestWiFi_access_in extended permit ip any any 
access-list ParkingInterface_access_in extended permit object-group TCPUDP any any object-group ParkingObj 
access-list ParkingInterface_access_in extended permit object-group TCPUDP any any eq domain 
access-list ParkingInterface_access_in extended permit ip any any 
access-list outside_access_in extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_SERVICE_1 any object ServerServer 
access-list outside_access_in extended permit icmp any any echo-reply 
access-list outside_access_in extended permit icmp any any echo 
access-list ServerTVAccessList extended permit tcp any host 192.168.96.2 eq https 
access-list ServerTVAccessList extended permit tcp any host 192.168.96.2 eq ssh 
access-list ServerTVAccessList extended permit tcp any host 192.168.96.2 eq 8090 
access-list ServerTVAccessList extended permit udp any host 192.168.96.2 eq 8090 
access-list ServerTVAccessList extended permit udp any host 192.168.96.2 eq snmp 
access-list ServerTVAccessList extended permit udp any host 192.168.96.2 eq 5001 
access-list ServerTVAccessList extended permit tcp any host 192.168.96.2 eq 5001 
access-list ServerTVAccessList extended permit tcp any host 192.168.96.2 eq 500 
access-list ServerTVAccessList extended permit tcp any host 192.168.96.2 eq 4500 
access-list ServerTVAccessList extended permit udp any host 192.168.96.2 eq 4500 
access-list ServerTVAccessList extended permit udp any host 192.168.96.2 eq isakmp 
access-list ServerTVAccessList extended permit icmp any any echo-reply 
access-list ServerTV_access_in extended permit icmp any any object-group DM_INLINE_ICMP_4 
access-list ServerTV_access_in extended permit object-group TCPUDP any any eq domain 
access-list ServerTV_access_in extended permit ip any any 
access-list WAN_OLD_access_in extended permit object-group TCPUDP xxx.xxx.xxx.0 255.255.255.0 object-group DM_INLINE_NETWORK_6 object-group ParkingPortsNAT 
access-list WAN_OLD_access_in extended permit ip object ParkingSystems object ParkingSystemSubnet 
access-list WAN_OLD_access_in extended permit ip any object ParkingSystemSubnet 
access-list WAN_OLD_access_in extended permit ip any any inactive 
access-list WAN_OLD_access_in extended permit icmp any any echo-reply 
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging asdm informational
mtu outside 1500
mtu inside 1500
mtu ServerTV 1500
mtu GuestWiFi 1500
mtu ParkingInterface 1500
mtu WAN_OLD 1500
no failover
no monitor-interface service-module 
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
icmp permit any inside
icmp permit any GuestWiFi
icmp permit any ParkingInterface
asdm image disk0:/asdm-762-150.bin
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
nat (inside,outside) source static any any destination static VPN_POOL_10.20.30.0 VPN_POOL_10.20.30.0 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (ParkingInterface,WAN_OLD) source static ParkingServer1 interface service any TCP_Parking_771
nat (ParkingInterface,WAN_OLD) source static ParkingServer1 interface service any TCP_Parking_771_U
nat (ParkingInterface,WAN_OLD) source static ParkingServer2 interface service any TCP_Parking2_9100
nat (ParkingInterface,WAN_OLD) source static ParkingServer2 interface service any TCP_Parking2_9100_U
!
object network GuestWiFi_NAT_OLD
 nat (GuestWiFi,WAN_OLD) dynamic interface dns
object network inside_NAT_OLD
 nat (inside,WAN_OLD) dynamic interface dns
object network ServerServer
 nat (ServerTV,outside) static interface
object network ParkingInterfaceOLD_WAN
 nat (ParkingInterface,WAN_OLD) dynamic interface dns
object network ServerTV2
 nat (ServerTV,outside) static WAN2
access-group ServerTVAccessList in interface outside
access-group inside_access_in in interface inside
access-group ServerTV_access_in in interface ServerTV
access-group GuestWiFi_access_in in interface GuestWiFi
access-group ParkingInterface_access_in in interface ParkingInterface
access-group WAN_OLD_access_in in interface WAN_OLD
route WAN_OLD 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 xxx.xxx.xxx.138 1
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 xxx.xxx.xxx.73 2
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 sctp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
http server enable
http 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 inside
http 172.16.64.0 255.255.248.0 GuestWiFi
http 10.20.30.0 255.255.255.0 GuestWiFi
http 172.16.17.0 255.255.255.0 ParkingInterface
http 192.168.96.0 255.255.255.0 ServerTV
http xxx.xxx.xxx.72 255.255.255.248 outside
http xxx.xxx.xxx.136 255.255.255.252 WAN_OLD
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
service sw-reset-button
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES192
 protocol esp encryption aes-192
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES
 protocol esp encryption aes
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES
 protocol esp encryption 3des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal DES
 protocol esp encryption des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto dynamic-map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP 65535 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256 AES192 AES 3DES DES
crypto map outside_map 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP
crypto map outside_map interface outside
crypto map WAN_OLD_map 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP
crypto map WAN_OLD_map interface WAN_OLD
crypto map TestLab_map 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP
crypto ca trustpoint ASDM_TrustPoint0
 enrollment self
 subject-name CN=HC-ClientASA
 keypair HC_Client_Odense
 proxy-ldc-issuer
 crl configure
crypto ca trustpool policy
crypto ca certificate chain ASDM_TrustPoint0
 certificate 50de3358
    30820551 30820339 a0030201 02020450 de335830 0d06092a 864886f7 0d010105 
    05003038 31173015 06035504 03130e48 432d416e 64657273 656e4153 41311d30 
    1b06092a 864886f7 0d010902 160e4843 2d416e64 65727365 6e415341 301e170d 
    31363131 32323039 34353430 5a170d32 36313132 30303934 3534305a 30383117 
    30150603 55040313 0e48432d 416e6465 7273656e 41534131 1d301b06 092a8648 
    86f70d01 0902160e 48432d41 6e646572 73656e41 53413082 0222300d 06092a86 
    4886f70d 01010105 00038202 0f003082 020a0282 0201009b bf07918b 21978e37 
    0a517ac1 5d1eb7a3 1dca77f7 054b0615 7a85096b 87b3d32f b86e61b5 78fa6364 
    08d932b7 2e73d1a9 1acdef89 a5cf7dd2 a9dfa34c b5086cd2 6f954b83 680c5fcc 
    dee06f08 7030ff8d 729458e4 59780d58 ae72b300 4a0b2e7a ac608cb7 cd5ce92a 
    39184d2e 3a7fd589 8ddbea50 bb4100a7 58dbc795 011181ae 34a92ba3 21a3d844 
    4ba72a10 2ce287e9 586dedbd 25b82e69 fd400b6f ce7de623 54a079f3 d0d096cb 
    fa2e69b7 1269aa84 ac5ed471 e2604897 aea282ca 27bb86b3 d3a78ac1 d8fcfc84 
    0e62f59f 71878e7d 0d6d052f e4fd7d90 374dc860 a3cd83e2 772e58de 77e29583 
    03ecd3d4 9df22a1a 5903cc62 8f781e4d 2ecb281b efe0b1e4 211e5953 bb5cec6e 
    0a260312 f85fd498 8adbd9e7 23e2e32c 9b034df9 839d9bbe aa769171 bb464bfe 
    be066806 d5d56cdc 22427990 08c8eb4a 93d676da 13bb9662 ad3bcb05 d29d8b9a 
    c800abd0 d4f482d5 c7cb8aa9 50d67062 61a33965 0c0aa305 e21b844c 95b12ed4 
    293e4b31 fc9300a5 367ae17f defd89b3 74b1e9e5 d44a93a3 19fa9df0 4e4e6bee 
    c64beddd d2541da6 d3a2699f 37f90b3a 8c190c9c 889c3856 ace813cb 6e4a0026 
    e10e2233 52dae76e 47b31549 0dc98652 14b2714a 3f60170a b3d3fb03 84adada8 
    eacff402 fc1b1158 9df65d60 3b8346ad b49da8ab dc9401cc b1402b46 ebd88db2 
    fa2d35a5 afa9b0e6 1985baa2 81f9dc97 024ec940 2fdf6102 03010001 a3633061 
    300f0603 551d1301 01ff0405 30030101 ff300e06 03551d0f 0101ff04 04030201 
    86301f06 03551d23 04183016 8014577e f2a6cd27 748802e9 0bc66c09 52098e7d 
    0fb3301d 0603551d 0e041604 14577ef2 a6cd2774 8802e90b c66c0952 098e7d0f 
    b3300d06 092a8648 86f70d01 01050500 03820201 0091f593 e31c5af8 4e8da415 
    039fcf93 bf770c4b f501da50 93dc9e57 f0f00b2e c7c2d53f 34547fcb 692976b3 
    337d293a 27d6f1be af40d76c cd78ef34 81a5cafc e9d60f7b 85de3870 5924468a 
    5dbba34f 63c1fe2c b14ab9b6 02634f45 7d40b61f 3d3a1378 8f4fafb4 9499bf7c 
    3784e9a9 fe4a7fac 3fb115b8 6e2b14e4 62bceea0 a8c5c5ba e2599857 f19c84ff 
    33f5f2a8 95c531ba d97d9e35 75f51081 e1451a22 60353ac7 2e2711d1 9e64fb52 
    45514b02 d362f07a bf874f23 f848da92 70ec10c8 f03741be 3bb28233 d78e95f8 
    26606b88 ff9f3f2a 8fe948eb 7005c9ed 9610cae9 90e4e6c1 69e98ec0 0e2debe7 
    d09a07cb ea159809 1dc1b666 a1401ea3 bb7e9203 f905c696 aee9d2f6 93978e82 
    4b6ec24e ab695964 64fd929c d0cfc46b dea848e5 d3cf56cb 08a2991f 7ddee7ef 
    5ed8869f 0be2a5ed dba14771 0d23ae29 6ebf7640 381106ff 99c1d56a 7d5ec7ad 
    cd432009 2ef4248e aa9b42b8 a71ead22 14b38dcb e343c945 064796d3 1e337d75 
    baccf54c 209b67f8 0e4e8fa8 cf7ce3f1 99cddf3b 18eced0d 770448aa 1b37d65a 
    09574ee9 d5985c00 bdb804c3 9c0e069e 9eaa50e3 b4694174 e17251b4 fc0bc169 
    845b7639 ebc47f37 894b5a5f d5662fa9 40b9898c 86a44b6b 805cb0ba 8607499d 
    2c330359 c0b30ef1 046b01b2 bad5d514 efea8647 55db6819 4eaf2da2 59e219b8 
    e8ff9053 f4e630b8 34f631c7 c49062a5 a0239c9a ef
  quit
crypto ikev2 policy 1
 encryption aes-256
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 10
 encryption aes-192
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 20
 encryption aes
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 30
 encryption 3des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 40
 encryption des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 enable outside client-services port 443
crypto ikev2 enable WAN_OLD client-services port 443
crypto ikev2 remote-access trustpoint ASDM_TrustPoint0
telnet timeout 5
ssh stricthostkeycheck
ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.72 255.255.255.248 outside
ssh 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 GuestWiFi
ssh 172.16.64.0 255.255.248.0 GuestWiFi
ssh 10.20.30.0 255.255.255.0 GuestWiFi
ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.136 255.255.255.252 WAN_OLD
ssh timeout 10
ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1
console timeout 0
management-access GuestWiFi

dhcp-client client-id interface outside
dhcpd dns 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
!
dhcpd address 192.168.1.5-192.168.1.254 inside
dhcpd dns 8.8.8.8 208.67.222.222 interface inside
dhcpd enable inside
!
dhcpd address 192.168.96.3-192.168.96.254 ServerTV
dhcpd dns 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 interface ServerTV
!
dhcpd address 172.16.64.2-172.16.64.250 GuestWiFi
dhcpd dns 8.8.8.8 208.67.222.222 interface GuestWiFi
dhcpd enable GuestWiFi
!
dhcpd address 172.16.17.33-172.16.17.250 ParkingInterface
dhcpd dns 8.8.8.8 8.8.8.8 interface ParkingInterface
dhcpd enable ParkingInterface
!
ssl trust-point ASDM_TrustPoint0 outside
ssl trust-point ASDM_TrustPoint0 inside
ssl trust-point ASDM_TrustPoint0 ServerTV
ssl trust-point ASDM_TrustPoint0 GuestWiFi
ssl trust-point ASDM_TrustPoint0 ParkingInterface
ssl trust-point ASDM_TrustPoint0 WAN_OLD
webvpn
 enable outside
 enable WAN_OLD
 anyconnect image disk0:/anyconnect-win-4.3.01095-k9.pkg 1
 anyconnect profiles Test_GuestWiFi_client_profile disk0:/Test_GuestWiFi_client_profile.xml
 anyconnect profiles VPN_Test_client_profile disk0:/VPN_Test_client_profile.xml
 anyconnect enable
 tunnel-group-list enable
 cache
  disable
 error-recovery disable
group-policy GroupPolicy_VPN_Test internal
group-policy GroupPolicy_VPN_Test attributes
 wins-server none
 dns-server value 8.8.8.8
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev2 ssl-client 
 split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified
 split-tunnel-network-list value Test_Guest
 default-domain none
 webvpn
  anyconnect profiles value VPN_Test_client_profile type user
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
username admin password xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx encrypted privilege 15
tunnel-group VPN_Test type remote-access
tunnel-group VPN_Test general-attributes
 address-pool Test_DHCP_VPN
 default-group-policy GroupPolicy_VPN_Test
tunnel-group VPN_Test webvpn-attributes
 group-alias VPN_Test enable
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect skinny  
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect netbios 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect ip-options 
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context 
no call-home reporting anonymous
Cryptochecksum:14a2b233fa9e205b5a530e7925ef77ac
: end
```

Comment: Which server please?

Comment: Hi hertil, sorry for not reply sooner, but issue us resolved (at least I think)... There are two routes, primary with metric 1, and secondary metric 2. What I did is set dyn NAT for interface with primary route and it is working... They can reach server via multiple wans from one subnet, and go out via different wan. The syntax was "object nat SetverTV_Nat   host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   nat (ServerTV, Wan_Old) dynamic interface"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to two WAN subnets, primary for guest wifi with default route with metric 1 and secondary WAN for TVServer with default route metric 2, secondary would never reach route 2 (as it is secondary) to go out with IP of the first subnet, instead I have set dynamic NAT for primary. The traffic will be inspected, and TVService provider will be able to get to the server via other IPs of second wan subnet. Syntax is quite simple: nat (TVServer,OLD_WAN) dynamic interface